# Adjusting width of timevis Gannt diagram in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am using the timevis package to make a Gannt diagram in R. When I open the diagram as a html (show in new window i Rstudio), it works pretty well. The depth of the diagram adjusts based on how much i zoom in. But the width is fixed, which leaves a lot of the screen un-used. Is there a way to make the whole diagram wider, so that the whole screen us utilized?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the argument 'width' to 100% within your call to timevis, that will fill the browser window when you pop out of RStudio.

```
library(timevis)

# define test data
data <- data.frame(
  id      = 1:4,
  content = c("Item one", "Item two",
              "Ranged item", "Item four"),
  start   = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11",
              "2016-01-20", "2016-02-14 15:00:00"),
  end     = c(NA, NA, "2016-02-04", NA)
)


#call timevis, and set width to 100%
timevis(data,
        width = '100%')
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the width of the group title column so it's e.g. only 5% of the width of the screen